# UpdatePanel - Show errors from server-side into client side div

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an updatePanel with asp:button inside it. Now on the button click, I am doing validations and wants to print the message to the screen. I want to show the message in the client side `<div>`.

I was hoping that I can leverage the EndRequest method of the PageRequestManager class to print the messages in the `<div>`.

Is there a way I can throw the error messages to the async error message and then pull it from the EndRequest method?

Pls suggest any approach.

I tried following the article given by Microsoft:- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx

This article works with the standard error messages, but I want to make it work with my custom error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript call to you validation call from server and pass the error/s string in the call and update the DIV on the client.

> Example:

```
function ShowError(msg)
{
  $get('divError').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

> On the Server

```
public btn_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
string Errors = "";
//Validation Block;
string script = "ShowError('(0}')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "",  string.Format(script,Errors),true);
}
```

I hope this helps; Please make sure you properly Encode the ErrorMessage to avoid missing literal errors on client end

Comment: sorry man, but the solution did not work in my case. The button is also present within the updatePanel. I tried to make it work. But nothing happened. ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock did not work for some reason..

Comment: The reason why the code might not have worked could be a un-formatted string in the function. for example ShowError('Please enter user name\n Error in value''). Please ensure the string returned is a valid ECMAScript and will not cause JS ERROR.